# How to send a float array to server using socket

Tags: android, sockets

Now I want to send data to server using socket on a regular basis. I put the data in a float array. However, It seems that write() can only be used when the array is byte array. So, how can I solve the problem? How can I change the float array into byte array?

```
public void transferdata(float[] a){
    Socket socket;
    try{
        socket=new Socket("192.168.1.32",1989);
        //InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(resultFileName);
        OutputStream outputstream=socket.getOutputStream();
       
        outputstream.write(a,0,0);
        outputstream.flush();

    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `outputstream.write(a,0,0);` You're writing 0 bytes!.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below method it will help you to convert float[] to bytes[].

```
public byte[] floatToByte(float[] input) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[input.length*4];
    for (int x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, x*4, 4).putFloat(input[x]);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: It works fine! Thank you! @Dharmender Manral

Comment: [FloatBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html) might be a little bit cleaner, maybe gets rid of those pesky "4"s.

Answer (score 0):

you can send it by converting your float value into byte with below code

```
public static final byte[] float2Byte(float[] inData) {
  int j = 0;
  int length = inData.length;
  byte[] outData = new byte[length * 4];
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     int d = Float.floatToIntBits(inData[i]);
     outData[j++] = (byte) (d >>> 24);
     outData[j++] = (byte) (d >>> 16);
     outData[j++] = (byte) (d >>> 8);
     outData[j++] = (byte) (d >>> 0);
  }
  return outData;
 }
}
```